# Openlayers 3.5 undefined coordinate

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to get the coordinates of the Circle drawing in ol 3.5. I use the evt.coordinate function to get the coordinates, but I keep getting undefined. Here's a piece of my code:

```
this.boundingCircle = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    condition: ol.events.condition.always,
    source: source,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: [50,50,255,0.5]
        }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: [0,0,255,1]
          })
      }),
    type: 'Circle'
  });
  this.boundingCircle.on('drawstart', function(evt) {
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    alert("coord " + coord);
  });
```

I ran out of ideas as to why I get ann undefined value for my coord variable. I tried using the same variable on my DragBox "boxstart" function and it works just fine, meaning I was able to get the coordinate of the initial click. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it with:

```
this.boundingCircle.on('drawstart', function(evt) {
    var geometry = evt.feature.getGeometry();
    var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
    alert("coord " + coord);
});
```